# How to calculate the order size

Tags: sum, case

I have to calculate  the cost of the order, which will include three packs of 'snacks', two packs of 'chips' and one piece of 'energy drink'. Name the column with the calculated order price order_price.

The columns in the table are: product_id, name, price.

The following structure below will work if the order has only 1 peices of each product.

SELECT sum (price) as order_price FROM   products
WHERE  name = 'snack'or name = 'chips'or name = 'energy drink'

SELECT sum (price) as order_price FROM   products
WHERE  name = 'snack' or name = 'chips' or name = 'energy drink'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try something like the following code. if you want to sum up all you articles in your order

```
SELECT sum (compute_order.compute_price) as order_price FROM (
  SELECT price*3 as compute_price FROM products WHERE name = 'snack'
  UNION
  SELECT price*2 as compute_price FROM products WHERE name = 'chips'
  UNION
  SELECT price as compute_price FROM products WHERE name = 'energy drink'
) compute_order
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).